# Deletion in binary search tree with parent pointers

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree, parent

I have been trying to solve an on-line challenge for 9 days now. I have an on-line insertion deletion with repetitions of 100,000 and I need to find the median of those. I tried two heaps but to realise random deletion doest work. I am now on to Binary Search trees since they seem to insert and delete 100,000 data in 2 seconds on my computer. I am working on python and I need to run in 16 seconds.

I have checked for solutions on-line but which exactly dont cater to my need. I figured out calculating the median while inserting and deletion could be a good strategy. This I wrote two methods which get the in order successor or predecessor of a node.

*The problem is as I figured it out to be is - improper assignment of parent pointers during recursive deletion.*

I tried two techniques, both of which didn't work well, I would appreciate if I get some help!

The code:

```
import sys
class BSTNode:
    def __init__(self,x,parent):
        self.data = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.count = 1
        self.parent = parent

def delete(x,T):
    if T is None:
        print('Element Not Found')
    elif x<T.data:
        T.left = delete(x,T.left)
    elif x>T.data:
        T.right = delete(x,T.right)
    elif T.left and T.right:
        TempNode = findMin(T.right)
        T.data = TempNode.data
        T.right = delete(TempNode.data,T.right)
    else:
        if T.left is None:
            T = T.right
        elif T.right is None:
            T = T.left
    return T

def findMin(T):
    if T.left:
        return findMin(T.left)
    else:
        return T

def insert(x,T,parent=None):
    if T is None:
        T = BSTNode(x,parent)
    elif x<T.data:
        T.left = insert(x,T.left,T)
    elif x>T.data:
        T.right = insert(x,T.right,T)
    else:
        T.count = T.count + 1
    return T

def inorder(T):
    if T is None:
        return
    else:
        inorder(T.left)
        b = back(T)
        if b:
            print("back:",b.data)
        print(T.data)
        n = next(T)
        if n:
            print("next:",n.data)
        inorder(T.right)

def preorder(T,i=0):
    if T is None:
        return
    else:
        for j in range(i):
            sys.stdout.write("    ")
        print(T.data)
        preorder(T.left,i+1)
        preorder(T.right,i+1)

def next(node):
    if node is None:
        return
    if node.right:
        n = node.right
        while n.left:
            n = n.left
        return n
    else:
        n = node
        while n.parent and n.parent.right is n:
            n = n.parent
        if n.parent and n.parent.left is n:
            return n.parent
        else:
            return

def back(node):
    if node is None:
        return
    if node.left:
        n = node.left
        while n.right:
            n = n.right
        return n
    else:
        n = node
        while n.parent and n.parent.left is n:
            n = n.parent
        if n.parent and n.parent.right is n:
            return n.parent
        else:
            return

T = None
T = insert(7,T)
T = insert(4,T)
T = insert(2,T)
T = insert(1,T)

T = insert(13,T)
T = insert(15,T)
T = insert(16,T)
T = insert(6,T)

T = insert(5,T)
T = insert(3,T)
T = insert(11,T)
T = insert(14,T)

T = insert(12,T)
T = insert(9,T)
T = insert(8,T)
T = insert(10,T)

T = delete(11,T)
T = delete(12,T)
T = delete(13,T)
T = delete(8,T)
preorder(T)
inorder(T)
```

output

```
7
    4
        2
            1
            3
        6
            5
    14
        9
            10
        15
            16
1
('next:', 2)
('back:', 1)
2
('next:', 3)
('back:', 2)
3
('next:', 4)
('back:', 3)
4
('next:', 5)
('back:', 4)
5
('next:', 6)
('back:', 5)
6
('next:', 7)
('back:', 6)
7
('next:', 9)
9
('next:', 10)
('back:', 9)
10
('next:', 12)
('back:', 10)
14
('next:', 15)
('back:', 14)
15
('next:', 16)
('back:', 15)
16
```

expected - back of 9 is 7

my answer

```
def delete(x,T,parent=None):
    if T is None:
        print('Element Not Found')
    elif x<T.data:
        T.left = delete(x,T.left,T)
    elif x>T.data:
        T.right = delete(x,T.right,T)
    elif T.count==1:
        # 2 CHILDREN
        if T.left and T.right:
            TempNode = findMin(T.right)
            T.data = TempNode.data
            T.right = delete(TempNode.data,T.right,T)
        # 0 CHILDREN
        elif T.left is None and T.right is None:
            T = None
        # 1 CHILDREN
        elif T.right is not None:
            T = T.right
            T.parent = parent
        elif T.left is not None:
            T = T.left
            T.parent = parent
    else:
        T.count = T.count - 1
    return T
```

now

```
9
    4
        2
            1
            3
        5
    14
        10
        15
            16
1 (2) 
('next:', 2)
('back:', 1)
2 (4) 
('next:', 3)
('back:', 2)
3 (2) 
('next:', 4)
('back:', 3)
4 (9) 
('next:', 5)
('back:', 4)
5 (4) 
('next:', 9)
('back:', 5)
9  
('next:', 10)
('back:', 9)
10 (14) 
('next:', 14)
('back:', 10)
14 (9) 
('next:', 15)
('back:', 14)
15 (14) 
('next:', 16)
('back:', 15)
16 (15)
```

Comment: what do you need to do for this challenge? A binary search tree will degrade into a linked list with random insertions and deletions if you do not do balancing.

Comment: Great dint know that!!! that might have taken a life time to figure out...i do want to balance it next, I could not find any proper resource, my text allen weiss has only theory for balancing during insertions! lame excuse! please let me know if u would be knowing better resource for that, thank you

Comment: My hunch is that you can solve your problem with Python's built-in `set`, no need to implement it yourself. Correctly implementing a balanced tree can be quite tricky... So more detail on what you are trying to achieve would be nice ;)

Comment: ooh!!! if python had a balanced bst that would be great, i thought it dint... im trying to find median of 100,000 elements which get inserted one by one after each time the median is found. im implementing and using bst to best insert and delete that amount and that frequent data. I maintain maximum of two pointers for median and keep updating them as new element inserted or deleted either falls on left or right side. I obtain the median from these pointers to print the median after ever insertion/deletion which is my challenge

Comment: You could try [blist](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist). If you can't use your own modules, you could try copy&pasting the relevant code from blist's source.

Comment: wow, thank you for the link and pointer. thank you

Comment: i hit on a dead end without being able to find algorithm for deletion in avl or bst thus figured out red black trees was the alternative. like mensi suggested, found a code at [http://newcenturycomputers.net](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/rbtree.html) and adapted it - [redblacktree.py](https://raw.github.com/pmontu/BSTPython/master/redblacktree.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be updating the parent pointers of T after `T = T.right` and `T = T.left` in the `else:` part of the `delete(x,T):` routine. Another option might be to update the parent pointers whenever you replace a left or right child. I think following either of the two conventions consistently throughout the code must solve your problem.

Comment: u mean after T = T.right now T becomes T.right so T.parent needs to be updated. that's exactly what I figured out to do recursively... Thank you

Comment: aah its u trss!! yup tried it, seems to work.. had issues thinking the recursive way till then... Thank you